# Chaining transition in javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity.js

I have a list that looks like this  :

[image]

Now I am having a requirement to animate the box which is clicked to the center of the screen, wait for .5 second and then move to the top as heading.

I have been trying out different option in velocity.js but unable to figure out how to do this.

```
function animateobject(objName, obj) {
debugger;
obj = $(obj);
var p = obj.offset();
var element = $('#' + objName);
element.html(obj.closest('.connectPan2List').find('p').html());
element.css('top', p.top);
element.css('left', p.left);
element.velocity({ top:'50%', left:'50%' }, { duration: 500, easing: "linear" })
        .velocity({ top: '10px' }, {
            duration: 500, easing: "linear", complete: function () {
                alert('');
            }});
```

}

Here I have been trying to transfer the element to the center of the screen and then move up to the top, but it seems I am unable to get it properly. Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: I'm not sure `var element = $('#' + objName);` is giving you what you want - you'll need to wrap the element identifier in quotes, but your line as it stands isn't. Make sure you either use string concatenation to put the quotes around it, or use an ES6 template literal, i.e. surround `$('#${objName}')` with backtick marks.

Comment: Yes thats right, but this section isnt giving any issue, even though the construct you mentioned might be a better in terms of readability. The problem lies on the last lines, the translation does not work. 

For your ref, the objName is returning the id of the element which holds the data which need to be replaced on runtime.

Comment: VelocityJS coder here - animating between different units is not a very good thing to do, so you need to make sure you use forcefeeding for the left and top rather than using jQuery to set them first. If you put together a working example it's a lot easier to see if anything else isn't working right...

Comment: @Rycochet I am totally new to this. Is it possible to give me an example of what I need to do. I actually want to highlight the text for 1 second and then move it to the top of the screen and load the rest of the screen.

Comment: @abhishek Have a look at the VelocityJS documentation - it's somewhat out of date (you can now animate "string123string" values for instance). Forcefeeding is just saying "start at this value" - so `top:[to, from]`. You can add a delay before it begins (so `delay:1000` to keep it in place before moving), then chaining is as you're already doing and adding one after another - they'll run in order when each finishes etc.